# WordPress admin panel - "quick edit" removes the list entry - add_theme_support reason?

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with WordPress 3.4.2. Google didn't come up with any solutions. Actually I didn't find somebody with the same problem.

Now to the problem, if I press "quick edit" on a post, it removes the post from the list (all posts list). If I reload the page, the post is there again. The only thing I added is this snippet in the *functions.php* (i made a complete theme, but i do not believe that the theme could cause this error):

```
<?php add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); ?>
```

Do you think that this is the issue? What else could cause this bug?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: firebug console if i press quickedit:
TypeError: p.suggest is not a function

Comment: It may be something to do with your theme. Try switching to a different theme, and see if the error persists. Another possibility is a conflict with a plugin.

Comment: all plugins are disabled and if i activate onther theme the problem happens, also

Comment: I would re-install Wordpress (just re-opload all files, except wp-content, and wp-config.php).

Comment: know i deleted even the database and reinstallt wordpress. without uploading my theme. the problem is still present. pls, could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i fixed it know:

1. i deleted all cookies from the page
2. then i deleted all cookies with wordpress in name
3. emptied the cache
4. disabled javascript
5. enabled javascript

and it works again. i have no idea, what could be the problem. i hope it won´t happen again.
thanks anyways to all